# Gitlab behind a NGinx reverse proxy - API doesn't work

Tags: nginx, server, gitlab, reverse-proxy

I have multiple containers behind a NGinx reverse proxy.

Here my docker-compose.yml:

```
 gitlab:
    image: gitlab/gitlab-ce:latest
    restart: always
    container_name: gitlab
    hostname: 'git.mydomain.local'
    environment:
      GITLAB_OMNIBUS_CONFIG: |
        external_url 'http://git.mydomain.local'
        gitlab_rails['gitlab_shell_ssh_port'] = 2224
    ports:
      - '2224:22'
    volumes:
      - /srv/docker/outils/etc/gitlab:/etc/gitlab
      - /srv/docker/outils/var/gitlab/logs:/var/log/gitlab
      - /srv/docker/outils/var/gitlab/data:/var/opt/gitlab
    shm_size:
      '256m'
    networks:
      - gitlab

  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    restart: always
    container_name: proxy
    volumes:
      - /srv/docker/outils/etc/nginx:/etc/nginx
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    environment:
      - NGINX_PORT=80
    networks:
      - wordpress
      - gitlab
    depends_on:
      - wordpress
      - wikimaint
      - phpmyadmin
      - gitlab
```

Here the NGinx config to redirect to the container:

```
upstream gitlab {
    server gitlab;
}

server {
    listen  80;
    server_name git.mydomain.local;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/gitlab.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/gitlab.err emerg;

    location / {
        #include proxy_params;
        add_header      X-Served-By $host;
        #underscores_in_headers on;
        proxy_pass_request_headers      on;
        proxy_set_header        Host $host;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Scheme $scheme;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Fort $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_pass http://gitlab;
    }
}
```

Everything works, I can access to my Gitlab through HTTP, clone, push, pull, etc.

But, I have a PowerShell script to query Git through the API to make a report about my repositories.

I try with this PS command:

```
Invoke-RestMethod -Headers @{'PRIVATE-TOKEN' = $sApiToken } -Uri "http://git.mydomain.local/api/v4/projects"
```

But I got an error:

> Invoke-RestMethod: {"message":"500 Internal Server Error"}

In the `/var/log/nginx/gitlab.log` I got this message:

> 10.x.x.x - - [24/Aug/2023:12:05:23 +0000] "GET /api/v4/projects HTTP/1.1" 500 39 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Microsoft Windows 10.0.22621; fr-FR) PowerShell/7.3.6"

Nothing in the log of the GitLab container.

If I remove the parameter `-Headers`, no error, but nothing is returned:

> 10.x.x.x - - [24/Aug/2023:12:07:25 +0000] "GET /api/v4/projects HTTP/1.1" 200 2 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Microsoft Windows 10.0.22621; fr-FR) PowerShell/7.3.6"

I don't know what happens.

I already looking for on Google, change NGinx parameter, nothing work.

Comment: Problem fix! Finally it was an issue with my gitlab-secrets.json.